# Forwarding messages with certain filter

Tags: linux, syslog, syslog-ng

Scenario is to receive all incoming messages and store all of those messages in `/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log`, but forward only certain messages(by filtering).

`filter` tag is used to filter incoming messages to Syslog-NG, which is not the right usage, in this scenario. For example: `filter f_warn { level(warn); };`

---

**Edit:**

My current configuration is:

```
@version: 3.17

source s_network {
        udp(
                flags(syslog_protocol)
                keep_hostname(yes)
                keep_timestamp(yes)
                use_dns(no)
                use_fqdn(no)
        );
};

destination d_all_logs {
        file("/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log");

};

log {
        source(s_network);
        destination(d_all_logs);
};
```

After storing all messages in `all_devices.log`, Does Syslog-NG provide syntax(configuration) to forward only certain messages(after filtering) to remote log server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple directives in your configuration file.

As an example, based on your code, you define a filter:

```
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
```

then a destination:

```
destination remote_log_server {
 udp("192.168.0.20" port(25214));
};
```

and put them all together with something like:

```
log { source(src); filter(f_warn); destination(remote_log_server); };
```

Obviously, you have to configure your `source`, `filter` and `destination` based on your needs.

I suggest you take a good read at the [official manual](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide), as there are *lots* of options to customize your logging.

Comment: Perhaps also take a look at `rsyslog` as an alternative to `syslog-ng`

Comment: Does filter tag not stop rest of incoming messages to syslog-ng? Because we want all messages to be stored in local file...

Comment: No, because by default every log path receives every message of the source. (You can use the flags(final) option to change this, see https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/48#TOPIC-956565 and https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/49#TOPIC-956570)

Comment: @RobertFekete I mean, Do I need to add one more log statement, to my existing configuration? Given in query...

Comment: Yes, so you'll have two, like: 
log { source(src); destination(local_file); }; 
log { source(src); filter(f_warn) destination(remote_log_server); };

Comment: @RobertFekete The second does forwarding to `remote_log_server`?

Comment: Yes. In syslog-ng, you have to define the sources and destinations, and connect them with log paths.

Comment: @RobertFekete Another related [query](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474305/62659)..